# How do I solve $\int _1^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: gaussian-integral

How do I solve

$$\int _1^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx?$$

I solved like this.

let $I = \int _1^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$

then $I^2 = \int _1^{\infty} \int _1^{\infty} e^{-x^2 -y^2} dxdy$

If I change the cartetian coordinate to the polar coordinate.

$I^2 = \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int _1^{\infty} e^{-r^2} rdrd\theta$

$= \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} [\frac{e^{-r^2}}{-2}] _1^{\infty} d\theta$

$= \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2e} d\theta$

$= \frac{1}{2e} \frac{\pi}{2}$

and then,

$ I =  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt\frac{\pi}{e}$

I got The solution is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi }{ e} }$

but in the integral calculator the answer is $0.13940279...$.(https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The answer isn't $\sqrt{\pi/e}$. Unless you share your method with us, we cannot tell where your error lies.

Comment: Until you [edit] the question to show us just how you  got your answer we can't possibly explain why it might be wrong.

Comment: I edited context. and I solved $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{e}}$

Comment: Are you bound to not use the [values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Table_of_values) of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)?

Comment: I want an exact solution, not an approximate one.

Comment: Your mistake lies in where you change the Cartesian coordinate to the polar coordinate. Try to plot the two areas and find the differences. Admittedly, your method is right if you integrate from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: The conditions $x \geq 1$ and $y \geq 1$ are not *equivalent* to $x^2 + y^2 \geq 1$ (they only imply that, but not the other way around, e.g., $x = \sqrt{2/3}$ and $y = \sqrt{2/3}$). There is no elementary exact solution.  The number just is what it is. You're hoping for too much if you expect the integral should have an elementary formula. Since $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}/2$ you could rewrite your integral as $\sqrt{\pi}/2 - \int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$, but this is not really "progress" since there is no elementary formula for $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Oh, I see.
The bound is wrong in two dimensions ...
And it's a pity that there's no exact solution.

Comment: @SukhyunPark Jacks' expression will be exact, because complex analytic functions will have Taylor series expansions which converge (and can be integrated) everywhere in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you consider $I^2$ you get the integral of $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ over the region $x,y\geq 1$, not the region $x^2+y^2\geq 1$.
Your integral simply equals
$$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}.$$

Comment: Hmm, how to get the sum? Is it some well known thing? Gamma function?

Comment: @mathreadler: just consider the Maclaurin series of $e^{-x^2}$ and perform a termwise integration over $(0,1)$. $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$ is fairly well-known and related to $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\dd x & =
{\root{\pi} \over 2}
\pars{{2 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{1}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\dd x}
\\[3mm] & =
\bbox[#ffc,15px,border:1px groove navy]{{\root{\pi} \over 2}\,\mrm{erfc}\pars{1}}\
\approx 0.1394
\end{align}

See [erfc Function in DLMF web page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E2) .